# Reading a single- array into a store

Tags: javascript, extjs

My store:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.NameStore',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;
        cfg = cfg || {};
        me.callParent([Ext.apply({
            proxy:{
                type:'ajax',
                url:'../api/AdminPanel/GetNames',
                reader:{
                    type:'json',
                    rootProperty:'data'
                }
            },
            fields:[{
                name:'name',
                calculate:function(data) {
                    var x = data;
                    return x.replace('<','&lt;').replace('>','&gt;');
                }
            }]
        },cfg)]);
    }
});
```

The data the store should take:

```
{"success":true,"data":["Axel Braun <axel.braun@contoso.com>","Andy Martin <amartin@contoso.com>","Charlotte Henrici <charlotte@contoso.com>"]}
```

I have tried to use the `json` reader and override "calculate" and/or "convert" function, but data is `undefined`.
I have also tried to use an `array` reader, because it seems natural. But for the `array` reader, the name is `str[0]` ("A") and the id is `str[1]` ("x"), before I even get to the `convert` function at all.

So, how can I convert a one-dimensional array of strings into a store?

Comment: Maybe a `transform` can help: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader-cfg-transform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to override [`Reader.getData`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader-method-getData) (in Ext 4) to convert your array of strings to be an array of objects.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.NameStore',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;
        cfg = cfg || {};
        me.callParent([Ext.apply({
            proxy:{
                type:'ajax',
                url:'../api/AdminPanel/GetNames',
                reader:{
                    type:'json',
                    rootProperty:'data',
                    getData: function(data) {
                        return data.map(function(str) {
                            return {emailSpec: str};
                        });
                    }
                }
            },
            fields:[
                'emailSpec',
                {
                    name:'name',
                    calculate: function(data) {
                        return data.emailSpec.replace('<','&lt;').replace('>','&gt;');
                    }
                }
            ]
        },cfg)]);
    }
});
```

In later versions, this function is called [`transform`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader-cfg-transform), as noted by [CD..](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139300/cd)

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.NameStore',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;
        cfg = cfg || {};
        me.callParent([Ext.apply({
            proxy:{
                type:'ajax',
                url:'../api/AdminPanel/GetNames',
                reader:{
                    type:'json',
                    rootProperty:'data',
                    transform: function(data) {
                        return data.map(function(str) {
                            return {emailSpec: str};
                        });
                    }
                }
            },
            fields:[
                'emailSpec',
                {
                    name:'name',
                    convert: function(data) {
                        return data.emailSpec.replace('<','&lt;').replace('>','&gt;');
                    }
                }
            ]
        },cfg)]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Because the root property is 'root', the ```getData``` function should call `data.data.map(function(str) {  ...`